# ASIHTTPRequest - HTTPS

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

Does ASIHTTPRequest support HTTPS connections? My connection right now works for a HTTP connection and errors if I try a HTTPS Connection. (Goes into requestFailed and gives me a ASIHTTPErrorRequestDomain)

```
-(void) getData
{

av.hidden = NO;
[av startAnimating];

NSString *urlString = [IP stringByAppendingString:@"Method1"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"URL = %@",url);
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setPostValue:@"val1" forKey:@"key1"];
[request setPostValue:@"val2" forKey:@"key2"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];    
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    //NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    // Use when fetching binary data
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    [self parseData:responseData];

    [av stopAnimating];
    av.hidden = YES;
}


- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    [av stopAnimating];     
    av.hidden = YES;
}
```

Thanks,
Teja

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whoops, sorry, figured it out -

`[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO]` works for reference.

Thanks to these guys - http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/29417-asihttprequest-library-works-https.html

EDIT: Since this is getting some upvotes, I'd just like to add that this might not be the best approach for valid SSL certificates. The one I was using was a self-signed certificate, so this was fine.

Comment: I think you mean "I didn't care if the data got intercepted & decrypted/changed by an attacker via a man-in-the-middle attack, so a self-signed certificate was fine". :-)

Comment: Haha true enough, it's actually a little more complicated than not spending 10 bucks and getting a certificate. We did buy the certificates from GoDaddy, but the certificate on our QA server had a hostname mismatch which lead to warnings on some browsers and plain rejection when using ASIHTTPRequest. Noone cared enough to fix it and here we are :)

Comment: Yea this is not a solution, but a workaround only. Which defeats the purpose for a server to use https(ecure).