# Simple Https POST - how to?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I was hoping someone could help me with figuring out how to POST to a https site?
I have bounced around SO for an hour now without finding a suitable answer.

I need to do this.

POST to https://somesiteontheweb.com/postform.aspx

The data I need to post is a simple pipe delimited string:  `username|password|variable|anotherVariable`

Response will be a string:  `loggedIN|information`

Does anyone have some simple sample code? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASIHTTPRequest is know for being simple and efficient. Do you use it ?

For your specific problem, you should find what you need [in another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730539/asihttprequest-https)

Answer (score 0):

[Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest)